Do fused Pokemon affect a challenge run?
I'm in a Gen 1 Challenge run, and I have Slowbro fused with Magneton.
If I use a stone to evolve the Magneton half into Magnezone, will I still be able to use the Pokemon, since Slowbro is the main Pokemon?
Or does it look at both halves of a fused Pokemon, and since Magnezone is Gen 4 I won't be able to use it?
Can't find the answer on the wiki


Well, it's been a few days with no answer so I decided to sacrifice my run for the sake of an answer, let's find out what happens:



Looks like it doesn't work. In a mono-gen challenge, both pokemon in a fusion have to be from that generation. It was a good run, Magneton did wonders, but now I've lost him for good as I'll have to unfuse and see if I can salvage this.
